# AJAX POST handler causing "uncaught exception"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

So I've been banging my head against my desk for a few hours on this one and i'm not getting anywhere so help would really be appreciated.

The code below has two jquery event handlers which fire off an ajax request. The first one uses GET and the data it gets back from the server is JSON encoded - it works fine. The second one ( "button#addTx" ) returns causes Firebug to produce this error:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult:
>   "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" 
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js
>   :: openTabPrompt :: line 468"  data:
>   no]
>
> Line 0

which is no help to at all. The server side script is printing raw html to the screen and the aim is that a jquery html replace will be used to update to the page which initiates the request. The data is POSTed correctly as the database updates but beyond that I have no clue. I have rewritten it to try a GET and still produce the same error :-(

Help would be amazing - thank you, Simon

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button.delete").click(function(){
    var txid = this.id;
    var amountID = "#amount" + txid;
    var amount = $(amountID).html();
    // <![CDATA[

    var url = "delete.php?txid=" + txid + "&am=" + amount;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function(msg){
            txid = "ul#" + txid;
            $(txid).hide();

            var values = msg;
            var e = "#" + values.category + "AmountLeft";
            var a = values.amount;

            $(e).html(a);
        }
    });
});
$("button#addTx").click(function(){

    // <![CDATA[


    var url = "addTran.php";
    //var dataV = var data = "category=" + document.getElementById("category").value + "&what=" + document.getElementById("what").value + "&amount=" + document.getElementById("amount").value + "&date=" + document.getElementById("date").value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addTran.php",
        //async: false,
        data: "category=Groceries&what=Food&amount=2.33&date=2/3/2011",
        success: function(msg){
            $("transList").replaceWith(msg);
        }
    });
});
});
```

and here is the server side script

```
<?php
session_start();
include('functions.php');
//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}


$category = $_POST['category'];
$what = $_POST['what'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$category = mysql_real_escape_string($category);
$what = mysql_real_escape_string($what);
$amount = mysql_real_escape_string($amount);
$date = mysql_real_escape_string($date);

$date = convertDate($date);

//add trans to db
include('dbcon.php');
$query = "INSERT INTO transactions ( category, what, amount, date) VALUES ( '$category','$what','$amount','$date');";
mysql_query($query);

//grab the remaining amount from that budget
$query = "SELECT amount_left FROM cards WHERE category = '$category';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$oldAmountLeft =  $row["amount_left"];

//update the amount left
$amountLeft = $oldAmountLeft - $amount;

mysql_free_result($result);

//add new value to db
$query = "UPDATE cards SET amount_left = '$amountLeft' WHERE category = '$category';";
mysql_query($query);



//generate the list of remaining transactions, print to screen to send back to main page

$query = "SELECT txid, what, amount, date FROM transactions WHERE category = ('$category');";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $d = convertDateReverse($row["date"]);
    $what = $row["what"];
    $amount = $row["amount"];
    $txid = $row["txid"];
    ?>
        <li><ul class="trans" id="<? echo $txid; ?>"><li class="date"><? echo $d; ?></li><li class="what"><? echo $what; ?></li><li class="amount" id="amount<? echo $txid; ?>"><? echo $amount; ?></li><button class="delete" id="<? echo $txid; ?>">Delete</button><li></li></ul></li>
    <?
}
mysql_free_result($result);



mysql_close();

header("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //do I need this? I have a " header("Content-type: application/json"); " in the working one

?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)? It will make your life easier. Also, that header() call at the end should not be there. If you want to set that, put it at the top and the Content-type should be text/html

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but if you are using jQuery, why don´t you just use jQuery's ajax functions? That would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Oh and the html where this data for all this is entered is: <form>
 `<select id="category">
  <option>Groceries</option>
  <option>Petrol</option>
  <option>Life</option>  
 </select>
 What: <input type="text" id="what" />
 Amount: <input type="text" id="amount" />
 Date: <input type="text" id="date" />
 <button id="addTx">Add</button>
</form>`

Comment: Hi Jeroen and Jesse, thanks for reply - I'm not using the functions as I only started using jquery yesterday so hadn't looked into it - I'll have look into it. May help solve the error. I'll also remove the header type at the end. Thank you

Comment: The error you're seeing in Firebug, is that from the Response tab for the request?  If not, what's in the Response tab?  And what happens when you navigate to the page (or, rather, post a form to the page) synchronously?  Going to a problematic page without Ajax can help to make sure it's solid before you add the complication of asynchronous calls to the mix.

Comment: Kyle, the error is in the console, I've taken a screen shot of it and hosted it [here](http://www.sufficientlyinteresting.com/error.png) if that helps. If I do it synchronously there is no error and the requested data comes back as expected. If I set the server page up to receive a GET and then hand code the url into the address bar I also get the expected page. Hope that helps - nice to see it works synchronously at least. thanks

Comment: Oh and the response tab is empty

Comment: Do you think that the subsequent line in the console may be of relevance? Do you get the data with Firebug disabled?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED: so in the html markup the form that holds the fields of data should have an

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

in it!

Thanks for all the help guys, I have implemented all your suggestions and my code is now soooo much smaller and easier to manage!

Cheers

Simon

Comment: onsubmit, wtf? Well thanks for posting this, you saved my day!

Comment: jQuery("#form").submit(function() { return false; });

Comment: the worst thing is that when you do a jQuery.ajax POST request, the error shows in Mozilla.  But if you do a jQuery.get GET request, it doesn't show, but when you implement this code, it then corrects both ways.  In IE, it just shows that you have an error.  I haven't tried Chrome.

Comment: By doing this instead, you don't need to prevent the submit (in case other things on the form need to call the submit), rather you are preventing the default behavior within the event for the AJAX call only.  I'm not sure if this code will work for everyone... jQuery("#<%=buttonControl.ClientID %>").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });

Answer (score 0):

Thx for posting the solution. Similarly banged my head for a while trying to solve a similar problem with NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE without luck. Useful for for people using Django <--> Javascript to do XMLHttpRequests as well.  On the Django side, there is an

```
   error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

...that corresponds with the NS_ERROR that appears in the firebug console for the JS failure.(googleBait)  It's hard to know where to start tracing the problem - server side or client side.

Thx again.