# Component returned failure code error 0x80040111 with JQuery Ajax Zend

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page has an anchor href to the home page and calls ajax on a user request.  If I open the page and click on the link to go to the home page it returns to the home page without error, but if I make the page call the ajax and then click on the link, I get the following error.

[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIXMLHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://local-www.crowdcloud.com/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js :: anonymous :: line 7401"  data: no]

The ajax appears to be working fine.  I'm getting back the data I need.  The link is as follows: 
Home
When I click on it I get the error message, but the page does go where directed.

Using Zend, JQuery 1.5.2

Comment: Note, I changed from 1.5.1.min.js to 1.5.2 (un-minimized) in order to see where the problem was and to make sure it wasn't JQuery.

Comment: Using window.location = '/admin/index'; seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're getting this in FF. It is a know problem.

What you are doing is causing the error event to be thrown when the ajax call is still in progress by clicking a link to another page.

If you then try and handle the error and access the error function's "errorThrown" property, you'll get this error.

Comment: I got this weird bug with firefox 7 and jquery 1.7 (it gives more infos about the error like 0x80040111) : I get this on all my ajax calls without doing other things such click a link to another page, directly in onComplete event (!). One more info is the ajax response in firebug is blank (Failed to load source for: http://localhost/...).
But you are talking about well known bug, I googlized and found some things such url call must be relative, etc...but nothing very clear, do you have some good links explaining how to get rid of ?

Answer (score 0):

after one hour of googling, finally an other stackoverflow answer worked well for this horrible bug : [AJAX POST handler causing "uncaught exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545577/ajax-post-handler-causing-uncaught-exception)
I got this error with an input submit and button submit, the solution is such :

```
<form ... onsubmit="return false;">
```

or

```
$('form').bind('submit', function(){ return false;});
```