# POSTDATA not being passed using javascript submit() function

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post

I'm trying to write a form that will update the hidden field values and then submit, after which the values will be input into the mysql database. However, while the form does seem to submit, the $_POST array seems to be empty and i get "unidentified index" errors whenever i try to access any of the $_POST elements??

The relevant code is as follows:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['a'])){
$title = $_POST['left'];
$sql = "UPDATE boxes SET topx = '".$_POST['left']."', topy = '".$_POST['top']."', width = '".$_POST['width']."', height = '".$_POST['height']."' WHERE id = '2'";
    // this is where I get "unidentified index" errors
mysql_query($sql);
}
else {
$title = "test";
}
?>
```

the JS function to fill the hidden fields and submit the form:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function dosmt(form){
JStopx = dd.elements.field2.x; alert(JStopx);
JStopy = dd.elements.field2.y; alert(JStopy);
JSwidth = dd.elements.field2.w; alert(JSwidth);
JSheight = dd.elements.field2.h; alert(JSheight);
alert("test2");

alert(document.getElementById('top').value);
document.getElementById('top').value = JStopy; alert("test1");
document.getElementById('left').value = JStopx;
document.getElementById('width').value = JSwidth;
document.getElementById('height').value = JSheight;
alert("waah");
location = "http://127.0.0.1/experiment/index.php?a=true";
alert ("OK"); 
document.getElementById('testform').submit();
}
</script>
```

and the form:

```
<form name = 'testform' method = "post" id = 'testform' action = "index.php">
<input type = "hidden" name = 'top' id = 'top' value = ''/>
<input type = "hidden" name = 'left' id = 'left' value = ''/>
<input type = "hidden" name = 'width' id = 'width' value = ''/>
<input type = "hidden" name = 'height' id = 'height' value = ''/>
<input type = "hidden" name = 'placeholder' id = 'placeholder' value = 'blah'/>
<input type = "button" name = 'update' id = 'update' value = "Update" onClick = 'dosmt(this.form)'>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `location` in JavaScript; if you do something like

```
location='http://example.com'
```

you're actually redirecting the page to example.com.

You should remove the line

```
location = "http://127.0.0.1/experiment/index.php?a=true";
```

and change it to something like:

```
document.getElementById('testform').action="http://127.0.0.1/experiment/index.php?a=true";
```

- [Read more about the `location` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location3)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your form, you go to `index.php`, not `index.php?a=true` - try doing

```
location = "http://127.0.0.1/experiment/index.php?a=true";
document.getElementById('testform').action = location;
```

Comment: check for js warnings/errors in firebug, check output of `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_GET)`

Comment: output of var_dump($_POST) is "array(0) { } "

Comment: i got one error after pressing the submit button that said "prompt aborted by user" and  

"throw Components.Exception("prompt aborted by user", Cr.NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)

nsPrompter.js (line 457)
<System>"

not too sure what this means though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545577/ajax-post-handler-causing-uncaught-exception

Comment: Don't do that. You can't use `location` as the name of the variable; assigning anything to `location` will redirect you to that url! See the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type = "button" name = 'update' id = 'update' value = "Update" onClick = 'dosmt(this.form)'>
```

with

```
<input type = "button" name = 'update' id = 'update' value = "Update" onClick = 'dosmt(document.testform)'>
```

Comment: changing it with "document.testform" also does not seem to work :(

i am pretty sure the function calls because I tested the hidden fields to see if they were updated (by changing the hidden fields to text fields) and they did get updated, its just that they dont get sent as post data.