# ajax request finishes after redirect

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a problem with an ajax petition, I have a function as follows

```
function do_ajax (params, url, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: params,
        success: function (response){
            try{
                var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
                callback(obj);
            }catch(e){
                alert('Cannot connect');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert('err');
            console.log(jqXHR)
            console.log(textStatus)
            console.log(errorThrown)
        }
    });
}
```

I call it with

```
function verificar_atenciones_paciente (p) {
    progress();
    do_ajax('', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/some/where/'+p.id, callback);
}

function callback (obj) {
    var table = $('#table tbody')
    var t = false;
    table.empty();
    if (0 == obj.length){ return; }
    $(obj).each(function (key, value){
        if (value.f){
            tiene = true;
        }else{
            alert('Redirect');
            window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/some/where_else/'+value.id;
            return;
        }
        var tr = to_row(value);
        table.append(tr)
    })
    if (tiene_fac){
        alert("Found!");
    }else{
        alert("Not Found!")
    }
    $('#list').fadeIn();
    done();
}
```

My problem comes when the redirection (`window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/some/where_else/'+value.id;`) is called It executes some ajax in background and shows the error for the ajax request (`alert('Cannot connect');`).

I am usign PHP, Code Igniter, JQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're swallowing the exception.  What's `e`?

Comment: `|[Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 425"  data: no]`

Answer (score 0):

Is this page returning JSON?

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/some/where/'+p.id
```

If it isn't, `parseJSON` might throw an exception. Try returning some JSON

```
echo '{"f":{"test":1},"test2":1}';
```

should do the trick.

I would also change the `alert()`'s to `console.log()`'s as it makes it easier to watch the progression with developer tools.

Comment: It does return JSON, The exception is in comment in the question. The problem is with the redirection because with out it, it works just fine..

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/q/5545577/183254 Looks like it might be an error with the way the js is handling the form

Comment: There is no form, actually. I guess the problem is with ajax request aborted.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax request is bind to a click event in a row table.. There is no form being posted (`onsubmit="return false;"`). I worked it arround using a setTimeOut and calling the redirection after two seconds to let the ajax post chain finish. I guess the problem is that The ajax request is interrupted abrubtally so it throws an exception. Since It delays the request, It let finish the ajax request normally and later do the redirection. I'd love to have some other suggestions..
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting

```
async: false
```

in your ajax request, which will cause it to hold up until the request is finished.